# NumberFormat text field without commas

Tags: java, string-formatting, number-formatting

I have a [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) which I want to accept numbers in the 5 digit range. The following code works correctly:

```
myNumberBox = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());
```

However, when I type "12345" into the field and switch focus, a comma is inserted due to my locale, making the text "12,345". How can I prevent commas from being added to my input? Better yet, can they be stripped out even if the user does insert commas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to disable the grouping in your NumberFormat object like this:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
format.setGroupingUsed(false);
myNumberBox = new JFormattedTextField(format);
```

See: [NumberFormat.setGroupingUsed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setGroupingUsed%28boolean%29)