# Arabic numbers in java

Tags: java

I was looking for formatting the numbers in java, then I found this code. It working as I wanted but the problem is when printing big number it has a comma. I don't want it to print the comma (I read java documentation but nothing helped)

```
Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag("ar-SA-u-nu-arab").build();
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale);
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
System.out.println(numberFormat.format(1239273203));
```

the output I want is:

```
١٢٣٩٢٧٣٢٠٣
```

the real output is:

```
١٬٢٣٩٬٢٧٣٬٢٠٣
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31708273/1712343), you need to do

```
numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);
```

between lines 3 and 4.

Comment: @markspace I'm not trying to be mean too but I used Google before you saw this question.